# Number of 1100 in periodic binary string of length $n$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A binary string is a sequence of $0$s and $1$s, e.g.,

> 101101100010111001011000010010011

And by the periodic condition we mean $a_1 = a_{n+1}$, where $n$ is the length of string.

**Question: How many numbers of $1100$s are there in all possible strings of length $n$?**

I want to write generating function $g(x)$, which will tell me how many $1100$s are there in the periodic binary string (or PBS) of length $n$. The method which I am familiar with is using a transfer matrix.

**Method:**
Let's say I want to count the number of $11$s in PBS. I can write the transfer matrix
$$T = \begin{pmatrix} x&1\\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
The largest eigenvalue of the transfer matrix is
$$\lambda_+ = \frac{1}{2} \Big(1 + x + \sqrt{5 - 2 x + x^2}\Big)$$

The generating function for a sufficiently large string is simply 
$$g(x) = n\ln(\lambda_+)$$
From this generating function, we can calculate the number of $11$s in the string. Similarly, we can go for the number of $01$s, $10$s, $00$s. **But how to go about finding 1100?**

See, I am not particularly interested in the Transfer Matrix Method. But, I will be happy to know if this could be extended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this simple solution works...

For each $k\in \{1,2,\dots,n\}$, count the number of strings $a$ for which $1100$ occurs at position $k$. That is, the number of binary strings for which $(a_k,a_{k+1},a_{k+2},a_{k+3})=(1,1,0,0)$.

If you add up, for each $k$, the number of occurrences of $1100$ at position $k$, then you get the total number of occurrences of $1100$.

Comment: Yes, I do not know why I was complicating things! But, from here writing generating function is straight forward, i.e., $g(x) = \sum a_nx^n = \frac{x}{8(1-2x)^2}$ where $a_n = n 2^{n-4}$.